# Koajs: How to handle static file with /.../... path

Tags: node.js, static, koa

if the path is /index or /something, the static files can serve "/main.css" which it works normally, but if the path is /pictures/uuid, the static files will serve "/pictures/main.css" which there is not that folder.

My CSS live in public/main.css

```
app.use(serve(path.join(__dirname + "/../public")));
```

Comment: Show us the FULL url the browser is requesting for the one specific resource that is not working. If it's not an absolute URL, then include the URL of the page the resource is being requested in so we can combine the two into what the browser will request. Then, show us exactly where the desired resource is located in your local file system relative to `__dirname`. We need all that info before we can advise what the proper serve code would be.

Comment: Is better if you use nginx to serve static files instead of using node...